# Dialog box size in Dynamics AX Report SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report, size, axapta

Anyone knows how to resize the dialog box for the report ssrs controller? I tried in build() method in UIBuilder with
**dialogFieldGroup.widthMode(FormWidth::ColumnWidth);**
I don't want to have scroll bar in the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

***Try this steps:***

1 - Get FormRun

```
dialog.formRun();
```

2 - Lock FormRun

```
FormRun.lock();
```

3 - Add/set yours controls.

4 - Call method resetSize()

```
FormRun.resetSize();
```

5 - Unlock form

```
FormRun.unlock();
```

If does not work try this

```
dialog.form().design(1).width("Your width value param);
```

Comment: Where should I copy it? In postRun() method in UIBuilder class?

Comment: Try to add this code in your Controller class, What is your Controller class exactly?

Comment: In Controller I have method main and preRunModifyContract() public static void main(Args _args)
{
    KPAssetDepreciationReportController srs;
    srs = new KPAssetDepreciationReportController();
    srs.parmReportName(ssrsReportStr(KPAssetDepreciationReport, AllAssets));
    srs.parmArgs(_args);
    srs.initParmDefault();
    srs.startOperation();
}

Comment: Ok, this is not a standard class or it belongs to a localization that I never worked. You'll have to follow the code, somewhere you should call `dialog`